# Show icons on jqgrid row mouse hover

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

How can i show the icons(Add, Edit icon etc) on jqGrid's hovered row and by clicking on icon I want to call JS function etc. I want to show the icons on each row.

Below is my jqGrid

```
$grid.jqGrid({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetOrganizationList", "Organization")',
                datatype: "json",
                height: 'auto',
                colNames: ['@objLocalizer["organization_organizationID"]','@objLocalizer["OrganizationsName"]', '@objLocalizer["ParentOrganization"]', '@objLocalizer["Email"]', '@objLocalizer["ContactPhone"]', '@objLocalizer["CurrencyID"]','@objLocalizer["CreatedByorg"]','@objLocalizer["CreatedOnorg"]']
                colModel: [{
                    name: 'OrganizationID',
                    index: 'OrganizationID',
                    sortable: true,
                    sorttype: 'number',
                    formatter: addLink,
                    align: 'center'
                },{
                    name: 'OrganizationName',
                    index: 'OrganizationName',
                    sortable: true,
                    sorttype: 'text',

                }, {
                    name: 'PratentOrganization',
                    index: 'PratentOrganization',
                    sortable: true,
                    sorttype: 'text',
                    align: 'left'
                },
                {
                    name: 'ContactEmail',
                    index: 'ContactEmail',
                    sortable: true,
                    sorttype: 'text',
                    hidden: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'ContactPhone',
                    index: 'ContactPhone',
                    sortable: true,
                    sorttype: 'text',
                    hidden: true,

                },
                  {
                      name: 'CurrencyID',
                      index: 'CurrencyID',
                      sortable: true,
                      sorttype: 'text',
                      hidden: true,
                  },
                    {
                        name: 'UserName',
                        index: 'UserName',
                        sortable: true,
                        sorttype: 'text',
                        align: 'left'

                    },
                {
                    name: 'WhenCreated',
                    index: 'WhenCreated',
                    sortable: true,
                    sorttype: 'text',
                    formatter: 'date',
                    align: 'center'
                }
                ],

                cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true, editable: true },
                autoResizing: { compact: true, resetWidthOrg: true },
                iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, "10000:All"],
                viewrecords: true,
                sortable: true,
                toppager: false,
                pager: true,
                rownumbers: false,
                sortname: "invdate",
                sortorder: "desc",
                pager: '#pjqgridOrg',
                pagerRightWidth: 150,
                loadonce: true,
                multiselect: false,
                hidegrid: false,
                gridComplete: function () {

                },

            }).jqGrid("navGrid")
            .jqGrid("inlineNav")
            .jqGrid("filterToolbar");
```

Formatter of first column 'OrganizationID'

```
 function addLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

        var validrow = rowObject.Organization;

        if (validrow != undefined) {
            return "<a href='#' style='height:25px;width:120px;' type='button'  onclick=CallActionMethod(" + "'" + OrganizationID + "'" + ")>" + OrganizationID + "</a>";
        } else {
            return "<a href='#' style='height:25px;width:120px;' type='button'  onclick=CallActionMethod(" + "'" + rowObject['OrganizationID'] + "'" + ")>" + rowObject['OrganizationID'] + "</a>";
        }
    }
```

and below is the screenshot how does it looks

[image]

I want to show the icons in the first column i.e '**OrganizationID**' column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add your custom buttons on row [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover) event like,

```
$("tr").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('td:first').append($("<span class='custom-btns'><button>Add</button><button>Delete</button></span>"));
  }, function() {
    $(this).find(".custom-btns").remove();
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
  datatype: "local",
  height: 250,
  colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
  colModel: [{
      name: 'id',
      index: 'id',
      width: 200,
      sorttype: "int"
    },
    {
      name: 'invdate',
      index: 'invdate',
      width: 90,
      sorttype: "date"
    },
    {
      name: 'name',
      index: 'name',
      width: 100
    },
    {
      name: 'amount',
      index: 'amount',
      width: 80,
      align: "right",
      sorttype: "float"
    },
    {
      name: 'tax',
      index: 'tax',
      width: 80,
      align: "right",
      sorttype: "float"
    },
    {
      name: 'total',
      index: 'total',
      width: 80,
      align: "right",
      sorttype: "float"
    },
    {
      name: 'note',
      index: 'note',
      width: 150,
      sortable: false
    }
  ],
});
var mydata = [{
    id: "1",
    invdate: "2007-10-01",
    name: "test",
    note: "note",
    amount: "200.00",
    tax: "10.00",
    total: "210.00"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    invdate: "2007-10-02",
    name: "test2",
    note: "note2",
    amount: "300.00",
    tax: "20.00",
    total: "320.00"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    invdate: "2007-09-01",
    name: "test3",
    note: "note3",
    amount: "400.00",
    tax: "30.00",
    total: "430.00"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    invdate: "2007-10-04",
    name: "test",
    note: "note",
    amount: "200.00",
    tax: "10.00",
    total: "210.00"
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    invdate: "2007-10-05",
    name: "test2",
    note: "note2",
    amount: "300.00",
    tax: "20.00",
    total: "320.00"
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    invdate: "2007-09-06",
    name: "test3",
    note: "note3",
    amount: "400.00",
    tax: "30.00",
    total: "430.00"
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    invdate: "2007-10-04",
    name: "test",
    note: "note",
    amount: "200.00",
    tax: "10.00",
    total: "210.00"
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    invdate: "2007-10-03",
    name: "test2",
    note: "note2",
    amount: "300.00",
    tax: "20.00",
    total: "320.00"
  },
  {
    id: "9",
    invdate: "2007-09-01",
    name: "test3",
    note: "note3",
    amount: "400.00",
    tax: "30.00",
    total: "430.00"
  }
];
for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);

$("#list tr").hover(function() {
  $(this).find('td:first').append($("<span class='custom-btns'><button>Add</button><button>Delete</button></span>"));
}, function() {
  $(this).find(".custom-btns").remove();
}).on('click', '.custom-btns button', function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="list"></table>
```

If your data is loaded dynamically then use [gridComplete event](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events).

Comment: After `$grid.jqGrid({...});` and Use table id(parent selector) when using hover like `$("table#grid tr").hover(function() {`

Comment: Not working.. can you please paste the full code/example

Comment: I have added like this which is only coming for first row and getting removed on mouse out.  `$grid.hover(function () {
                $(this).find('td:first').append($("<span class='custom-btns'><button>Add</button><button>Delete</button></span>"));
            }, function () {
                $(this).find(".custom-btns").remove();
            });`

Comment: Not sure why this is not working. I am using free jqGrid version 4.14.1-pre. Is this the problem ?

Comment: Thanks for the help ! it worked ! I have added it in `gridComplete function()`

Comment: Is this answer has not solved your problem? Or do you have another problem?

Comment: Can you please see the latest screenshot ?

Comment: Add `setTimeout(function(){/*hover code*/},500)` to prevent this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147058/discussion-between-rohit-and-rohan-kumar).